# i see some symbols in my page, when refresh it

Tags: html, dom

when i refresh my page, one moment it shows

### ï»¿ï»¿

symbols, only after it the normal page!

---

i've set  `charset=UTF-8` in my page
could you help me?
thanks

### UPDATE:

[here](http://24kadr.am/rules) is the link to my page

Comment: Could you provide a link to the page sop we can see/test?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the browser is interpreting the page as something other than UTF-8, reaching the meta data, then correcting.

Use a [real HTTP header](http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset) instead.

Answer (score 0):

does it help to save the file as utf-8 from the editor?